# R data.table - only keep rows with duplicate ID (most efficient solution)

Tags: r, data.table

I want to use `data.table` to create a function that only keeps rows where the ID column(s) - stored as a vector of strings - are duplicated. Note that where there are multiple ID columns, I only want to keep rows where the combination of ID columns is duplicated.

```r
library(data.table)

dt <- data.table(x = c(1:5,5), y = rep(c(1,3,5), each = 2), z = rep(1:3, 2))

get_duplicate_id_rows1 <- function(dt_in, id_str) {
  dt_in[, if(.N > 1) .SD, by = id_str]
}

get_duplicate_id_rows1(dt, c("x", "y"))
#>    x y z
#> 1: 5 5 2
#> 2: 5 5 3

get_duplicate_id_rows1(dt[, .(x,y)], c("x", "y"))
#> Empty data.table (0 rows and 2 cols): x,y
```

As above, my first attempt works when the data table has one non-ID column. However, when all of the columns are ID columns, then the data table has no rows. I think this is because, as per `?data.table`, `.SD` includes all variables of the original data table, except the grouping rows. Consequently, `.SD` has zero columns, which seems to be causing my issue.

```r
get_duplicate_id_rows2 <- function(dt_in, id_str) {
  dt_in[, if(.N > 1) .SD, by = id_str, .SDcols = names(dt_in)]
}

get_duplicate_id_rows2(dt, c("x", "y"))
#>    x y x y z
#> 1: 5 5 5 5 2
#> 2: 5 5 5 5 3

get_duplicate_id_rows2(dt[, .(x,y)], c("x", "y"))
#>    x y x y
#> 1: 5 5 5 5
#> 2: 5 5 5 5
```

My second attempt tries to circumvent my issues with my first attempt by using `.SDcols`. This does resolve the issue where all the columns in my data table are ID columns. However, here the column names in `id_str` are duplicated.

I think this is because one set of column names comes from the `by` argument and the other set of column names comes from `.SDcols`, although I'm not certain about this, because in my first attempt, the resultant data table had zero *rows*, not zero *columns*.

**Consequently, I'd love to understand what's going on here, and what the most efficient solution to my problem is - particularly for large data sets, which is why I'm moving from tidyverse to data.table.**

<sup>Created on 2020-04-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `.I` to get the index of groups with frequency count greater than 1, extract the column and subset the data.table

```
dt[dt[, .I[.N >1], .(x, y)]$V1]
```

NOTE: It should be faster than `.SD`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another option:

```
dt[dt[rowid(x, y) > 1], on=.(x, y), .SD]
```

In the example, your explanation for returning 0 row is correct. As grouping columns are used for grouping, it will be identical for each group and can be accessed via `.BY` and hence `.SD` need not have these columns to prevent duplication.

By default, when `by` is used, these are also returned as the leftmost columns in the output, hence in `get_duplicate_id_rows2`, you see x, y and then columns from `.SD` as specified in `.SDcols`.

Lastly, regarding efficiency, you can time the various options posted here using `microbenchmark` with your actual dataset and share your results.

Comment: 1. I'm never actually using `id_str = c("x", "y", "z")`.
2. Makes sense!
3. Of course! More looking to know why certain options are more efficient than others. Apologies if that wasn't clear.

Comment: oh i misinterpreted *However, when all of the columns are ID columns, then the data table has no rows.*. What do you mean by this?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear! See the output of `get_duplicate_id_rows1(dt[, .(x,y)], c("x", "y"))`. Also, your answer produces a third column, `i.z`, which is not equal to `z` for all rows.

Comment: added a `.SD` and your understanding of why it returns 0 rows is correct i.e. *I think this is because, as per ?data.table, .SD includes all variables of the original data table, except the grouping rows. Consequently, .SD has zero columns, which seems to be causing my issue.*